# How to use BouncyCastle for calculating Message Digests?

Tags: java, hash, bouncycastle

I'm currently playing around with Java and hashing.

I came across [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) when I was looking around online, I got it installed in my IDE and everything.

But, how do I use it to hash a text using the algorithms found [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html)? (Look for section 5.2 Algorithms)

I only want to use the digest algorithms as defined in this section:

> GOST3411 - MD2 - MD4 - MD5 - RipeMD128 - RipeMD160 - RipeMD256 - RipeMD320 - SHA1 - SHA-224 - SHA-256 - SHA-384 - SHA-512 - SHA3-224 - SHA3-256 - SHA3-384 - SHA3-512 - Skein-256-* - Skein-512-* - Skein-1024-* - Tiger - Whirlpool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've completely edited my answer, given the clarification of the original question. To hash a string with an SHA-512 digest algorithm, you need to register BouncyCastle with the JVM, then, you can use the Java APIs or BouncyCastle classes directly.

E.g. Java APIs

```
// register the BouncyCastleProvider with the Security Manager
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

String plainString = "Plaintext Secret";

MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
byte[] hashedString = messageDigest.digest(plainString.getBytes());

doSomething().with(hashedString);
```

Alternately you can use the BouncyCastle API directly, but it is better (IMO) to use the Java APIs for portability, if you can. (What if you find a library that is better than BouncyCastle? Doubtful, but you see the point.)

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

String plainString = "Plaintext Secret";

// instantiate the BouncyCastle digest directly.
MessageDigest messageDigest = new SHA512Digest();
byte[] hashedString = messageDigest.digest(plainString.getBytes());

doSomething().with(hashedString);
```

Comment: Well, I don't want to use the block ciphers, I just want to use the digest algos..

Comment: @artjom-b I"m not recommending anything. It was just an example on how to construct a complete algorithm. Future readers, please do not take this as a suggestion on recommended practices.

Comment: @artjom-b, you realize that the code I added to the original answer is directly from the BouncyCastle page linked in the question, right? Given he's edited the question, I've submitted a better answer.

Comment: Well, it looks like if you only add Bouncy Castle provider via Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());, and invoke MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512"), the instance returned will not be Bouncy Castle implementation.  Since Sun provider also supports SHA-512 algorithm and since it is first in the provider list, Sun implementation will be used.  You need to call MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512", "BC") to actually obtain Bouncy Castle implementation (Or use Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1) to add insert the Bouncy Castle provider first in the provider list.